# Make program ignore windows version

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a program that is designed to run on Windows XP - Windows 7. I need to get it installed on Windows Server 2003 but it comes up and says:

> You cannot install on this version of windows.

Not very descriptive and not very helpful. I tried getting it to work with compatibility mode, but no luck.

My specific question is, is there a wrapper I can run or something I can do so that the program thinks for all intents and purposes that it's running on Windows XP?

It seems to be a custom (.exe) installer, I tried extracting the contents and I didn't get anything useful to indicate what it was.

Comment: Knowing _which_ installer (MSI, InstallShield, etc) would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: @jscott added to question.

Comment: I'm in a struggle! Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on July 14, 2015. The big picture in this question is quite interesting and somewhat relevant, but using clearly EOL software & a program against how it was designed to be used makes this generally off-topic.

Comment: Does this program install DLL, or drivers?  If not, you could possibly just copy the files from a XP install to the 2003 server.  There are also 3rd party programs you can use that will snapshot the before/after states of an install and show you want an installer is doing, if you are lucky that can be used to force an install on an unsupported system.

Comment: @Zoredache I did try that, but it's got too many parts for me to be able to do a lot of that. I was sort of hoping for a wrapper to run the program in, but have found nothing. I even considered attaching a debugger and jumping forward past the OS check. (Last resort, but I may not do that at all now) Thanks though, I may try the snapshot program before hand though.